# Why do I have to use [0] after a jQuery query

Tags: jquery

Give that code:

```
 var lastVisibleElement =$('#test > div:visible').last()[0];
```

Why do I have to use [0] to get my html. What is the [0] for?

Comment: the `[0]` retrieves the DOM node, Without it you get a jQuery object. See http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

Comment: Because a jQuery selector result behaves like an array of matched nodes, even when you've asked it to contain one node only.

Comment: is there no convinient getDomNode method?

Comment: yes you have `.get(0)` but accessing directly into the array will save you an extra `jQuery` call

Comment: @Elisa Your main problem is that jQuery selector results are *groups* of nodes. Surely those groups might only have a single node, but there's no "get the one and only dom node" method as there might be more nodes inside of one selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array notation `[0]` is used to get a reference to the actual DOM elements instead of the jQuery object.

```
$( "#foo" )[ 0 ]; // Equivalent to document.getElementById( "foo" )
```

[Read this](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/)

Answer (score 2):

Just use console.log() to analyse this yourself

```
var lastVisibleElement = $('#test > div:visible').last()
console.log(lastVisibleElement);
```

You will see jQuery results/matches are returned as an object with an array type wrapper. So [0] simply refers to the first element. If using for loops the eq(num) function comes in handy

```
var objects = $('.selector');
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    console.log(objects.eq(i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating new elements (or selecting existing ones), jQuery returns the elements in a collection of jQuery objects. jQuery provides a method named `.get()` which instead of returning a jQuery-wrapped DOM element, it returns the DOM element itself.

```
// Selecting only the first <h1> element on the page.

var firstHeadingElem = $( "h1" ).get( 0 );
```

Alternatively, because the jQuery object is "array-like," it supports array subscripting via brackets:

```
// Selecting only the first <h1> element on the page (alternate approach).

var firstHeadingElem = $( "h1" )[ 0 ];
```

From: [The jQuery Object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/)